# Set active class in nav bar with JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I have the following elements in my navbar.

```
<div class="nav-languages">
      <a class="navbar-brand active" id="langStyle" href="/language/it"> ITA </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="langStyle" href="/language/en"> ENG </a>
</div>
```

After clicking on `a` links, I need to add the class "active" to the clicked element and remove the class "active" to the others.
My jQuery is the following:

```
  $('.nav-languages a').click(function() {
      $('.nav-languages a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```

Right now, soon after clicking, the clicked element correctly changes color becoming active, while the other turns to inactive. But as soon as the page ends to load, the situation goes back to previous state.

I've read lots of answers to similar questions but no one helped me to solve my issue..

Please note that I'm totally new-by in jQuery & js.

Thank you for any help you could provide.

EDIT: I'm using Django-Python

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', webprojects_home, name="homepage"),
    url(r'^language/(?P<language>[a-z\-]+)/$', language),
    ]
```

and

**views.py:**

```
### setting language session
def language(request, language='it'):
    response = HttpResponse("setting language to %s" % language)
    response.set_cookie('lang', language)
    request.session['lang'] = language
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: Your jQuery loads every time with your page load, so basically `.click` function will never run. You have to apply some logic on html part to check which link should have `active` class.

Comment: `#langStyle` should not be duplicate.

Comment: Yes, the page changes but as soon as the page finishes loading the situation goes back to previous state.

Comment: When you change pages your navbar is going back to the default state, so you need each page to set which element is active.  If you weren't changing pages then you'd see the changes you're looking for, but it wouldn't be much use without actually loading the page you've clicked.

Comment: @Mr.Developer: thank you, you are right, I make #langStyle a class

Comment: Is the navbar hardcoded in each page, or do you have it in some sort of template?

Comment: In this case you should use jquery cookie, which will be remember anchor tag should have active class.

Comment: @Mr.Developer You could come to the site from elsewhere and the active link would be incorrect, or when you click back/forward, it wouldn't change.  Sorry, but that's a very flaky suggestion.

Comment: @Archer Yes you are right as per user experience, but I am just saying about possibilities about of what he is asking in the question. I know this is not good approach

Comment: @Archer: I'm using a template https://pastebin.com/y3pYvQ7P

Comment: @user123892 That's a complete page.  If you have one for every link then simply change which link has the active class in each page.

Comment: @Archer: I do not have a page for each link, that is a template. I'm using Django-python, each link points to a url (languages/it or languages/en); both the urls point to the same view function which loads the same template. I edit the question adding the view file.

Comment: You've got the active class hard-coded in the page though, so no matter what page you go to, it will always be the same link that has that class name.

Comment: @Archer: I see.. How should I proceed?

Comment: @user123892 please update your question with adding specific programming language tag : like if it is python then add [tag:python]

Comment: @Archer: thank you, now I perfectly see my problem. Not yet the solution but the hunt is on!

Comment: I think you just need a rethink of the problem and you'll find an easy solution.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem without jQuery by simply reading the current Django session language and use this info to manually set the class active to the correct link.

```
 {% if session_language == 'it' %}
  <a class="navbar-brand active" href="/language/it"> ITA </a>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/language/en"> ENG </a>
  {%else%}
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/language/it"> ITA </a>
  <a class="navbar-brand active" href="/language/en"> ENG </a>
  {%endif%}
```

not very elegant, but simple and effective :-)

Thank you all for the support!

Answer (score -2):

Simple...
The jquery code is going to be:

```
$('.nav-languages a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active")
    $(this).siblings("a").removeClass("active")
});
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: The code in the question is correct - it's the expected outcome that is incorrect.  Note that when someone clicks an anchor tag (link) it changes the page so *all* DOM changes you make with jQuery are immediately lost.